# How to check is it reply to comment or comment to post in wordpress?

Tags: php, wordpress, forms, wordpress-theming

I would like to have two different comment forms for **comment** and **reply** in wordpress.

where my main different in form is submit button. 
if it is comment, show submit button as **Leave a comment**
[my Form should be like this if comment](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8FiW7.jpg)

if it is reply, show submit button as **Leave a Reply**
[my From should be like this if reply](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EQlaJ.jpg)

Thanks in Advance...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inside your `comment_form`, add this:

```
'label_submit' => isset($_GET['replytocom']) ? __('Leave a reply', 'wpse') : __('Leave a comment', 'wpse'),
```